# Abstração de código

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, abstração

Estou criando um projeto de perguntas e respostas, mais pra consolidar meus conhecimentos e adquirir outros. Mas ao desenvolvê-lo cheguei em uma questão que estou pensando em qual das opções seria melhor pra criar um model e por consequência uma tabela limpa e fácil de entender.

O que tenho é a seguinte dúvida: Qual das opções (dentre as quais eu pensei que seria bom fazer) é a melhor?

- Eu colocar no meu model de perguntas um atributo chamado *OpcoesResposta* com todas as opções que a questão traz (a, b, c, d, e) e outro chamado *Resposta* e nele colocaria a resposta correta da pergunta; ou
- Colocar quatro atributos (*Opcao1*, *Opcao2*, *Opcao3*, *Opcao4* e *Opcao5*) e outro chamado *Resposta* com a resposta correta.

Eu, particularmente, penso que a segunda opção seria a melhor, até pra que na hora que for responder a questão, eu poder puxar elas do banco e colocar em *radio buttons* e fazer `if`'s para verificar qual o usuário respondeu e verificar se aquela opção é a correta ou não.

Alguém tem alguma outra ideia que seja melhor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu faria o seguinte:

```
public class Pergunta {
    [Key]
    public Guid PerguntaId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("OpcoesResposta")]
    public Guid RespostaCorretaId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String TextoPergunta { get; set; }

    public virtual OpcoesResposta RespostaCorreta { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OpcoesResposta> OpcoesRespostas { get; set; }
}

public class OpcoesResposta {
    [Key]
    public Guid OpcoesRespostaId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String TextoResposta { get; set; }
}
```

Vai mais pela alternativa 1, com algumas nuances. Você deverá colocar na View algo assim:

```
foreach (var opcao in OpcoesRespostas) {
    @Html.RadioGroup("RespostaEscolhida", opcao.TextoResposta, opcao.OpcoesRespostaId)
}
```

E no Controller:

```
public ActionResult Acao(String RespostaEscolhida) {
    ...
}
```

O valor selecionado em tela será preenchido dentro de `RespostaEscolhida`.

---

**EDIT**

Supondo que na verdade estou recebendo um questionário vindo da `View`, eu faria um `ViewModel` em que eu tenha nele um conjunto de perguntas:

```
public class QuestionarioViewModel {
    public ICollection<Pergunta> Perguntas { get; set; }
}
```

O `Controller` teria uma `Action` para inicializar as perguntas:

```
public ActionResult Questionario() {

    var questionario = new QuestionarioViewModel {
        Perguntas = context.Perguntas.Take(10).ToList();
    }

    return View(questionario);
}
```

A `View` teria algo assim:

```
@model SeuProjeto.ViewModels.QuestionarioViewModel

foreach (var pergunta in Model.Perguntas) {
    ...
}
```

E, por fim, o `Controller` receberia:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Questionario(QuestionarioViewModel questionario) {
    // Coloque aqui a regra de negócio, obtendo o resultado dentro de questionario.Perguntas
}
```

Comment: Também pensei dessa forma Cigano, mas achei que iria prejudicar a performance do sistema. E só uma dúvida ali em _OpcoesResposta_, aquele atributo _Guid_, eu nunca usei ele. Ele faz tipo um _Dictionary_ ? Ou seja, um array com as opções de resposta. Porque tem aquele _foreach_ na view pra varrer o que tem no model.... E outra, teria como colocar algum exemplo de código no _controller_ ?

Comment: Não prejudica tanto assim. O *Guid* é um tipo especial que gera uma chave única e serve como chave primária. Fique à vontade para usar `int` no lugar, se quiser. Vou melhorar o exemplo pra você.

Comment: Entendi. Mas me surgiu outra dúvida... Se eu colocar todas as opções de resposta num campo só, como que eu faria pra varrer todo aquele conteúdo e colocar em um radiogroup e mais, como que faria pra ver o que selecionado é a resposta certa ou não ?

Comment: Ficaria bem mais complicado deste jeito: você teria que inventar um jeito de separar a informação de modo a montar um `RadioGroup` válido e montar a resposta. Não há necessidade de usar uma estrutura de dados mais simples apenas para obter eficiência.

Comment: Mas dessa forma que você colocou na resposta, é parecido certo ? Se coloca todas as opções de resposta em um único campo e depois monta o _radiogrouplist_ né ?

Comment: Então, na verdade pra "colocar em um único campo" é montando o `RadioGroup`. O que eu faço na resposta é simplesmente separar resposta a resposta pra que o Razor possa escrever um ítem de `RadioButton` por resposta. O agrupamento se dá pelo primeiro argumento do `@Html.RadioGroup()` (no caso, `RespostaEscolhida`).

Answer (score 2):

Bom vou contribuir com um exemplo próprio, faria assim basicamente: Um relacionamento de 1 para N (1 para muitos), entre **Perguntas** e **PerguntasItens**, onde seriam cadastrados a Pergunta e depois os Itens dessa pergunta. No final no campo da tabela Perguntas tem uma campo `PerguntaItemId` que seria a resposta correta em relação a Pergunta, código vindo da tabela de relacionamento, no caso, são processos nos quais o primeiro cadastra as perguntas e os seus itens de resposta e no final diz a pergunta qual resposta é a correta, informando o código no campo `PerguntaItemId`.

Tabelas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Models:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
public partial class Perguntas
{
    public Perguntas()
    {
        this.PerguntasItens = new HashSet<PerguntasItens>();
    }
    public int PerguntaId { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public int PerguntaItemId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PerguntasItens> PerguntasItens { get; set; }
}    
public partial class PerguntasItens
{
    public int PerguntaItemId { get; set; }
    public int PerguntaId { get; set; }
    public string Resposta { get; set; }
    public virtual Perguntas Perguntas { get; set; }
}
public partial class DbPerguntas : DbContext
{
    public DbPerguntas()
        : base("name=DbPerguntas") { }
    public DbSet<Perguntas> Perguntas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PerguntasItens> PerguntasItens { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Nossa, extremamente útil a sua resposta ! Muito simples. Olhando por este seu lado ficou mais claro pra mim. Eu estava fazendo uma tabela só e nela tem a pergunta e a resposta, sendo que a resposta seria um _IENUMERABLE_. O que talvez não seria uma boa. Porque eu preciso conseguir gerar uma lista que eu possa colocar em um _radiobuttonlist_ pra pessoa escolher dentre as alternativas, a correta !

Comment: Caro @ÉrikThiago, assim, seria muito tranquilo e com entity um PerguntaId já traz todas as informações daquela pergunta. Acredito que esse modelo vai ter servir muito.

Comment: E dessa forma eu conseguiria fazer um _radiobuttonlist_ sem problema algum e fazer a verificação da resposta ?

Comment: Sim!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Demoorooou ! Valeu ! Vou fazer a verificação da resposta por _if_ !